# Converter todos os arquivos do Environment em '.Rda' e, após, carregá-los de uma só vez com um loop

Tags: r

Quero converter TODOS dataframes do meu Environment em arquivo do tipo `.Rda`. Meu objetivo é, após essa ação, reiniciar o R e carregar todos eles de uma vez com um loop `for`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aqui vai uma resposta mais automática, caso você tenha muitos data frames e não queira escrever o nome de cada um de forma manual.

Primeira parte explicando como salvar todos os data frames do environment:

```
# criar dados (apenas dois data frames no environment)
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(runif(12), nrow = 3))
df2 <- data.frame(matrix(runif(12), nrow = 3))
vec <- runif(12)
list <- list(runif(12), runif(12))

# obter os nomes dos data frames do environment
dflist <- names(Filter(is.data.frame, as.list(.GlobalEnv)))

# criar uma nova pasta para salvar os Rda's (showWarnings = FALSE para não mostrar os erros se a pasta já existir)
dir.create('dataframes', showWarnings = FALSE)

# salvar todos os data frames
for(i in dflist) {
  saveRDS(object = get(i), file = paste0('dataframes/', i, '.Rda'))
}
```

Agora para ler todos os data frames salvos de forma automática:

```
# lista com os nomes dos data frames
dfNames <- dir('dataframes')

# retirar '.Rda'
objNames <- sub('\\.Rda$', '', dfNames) 

# ler os data frames
for(i in 1:length(dfNames)) {
  assign(objNames[i], readRDS(file = paste0('dataframes/', dfNames[i])))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Converte data.frames em lista

```
df1 = data.frame(x=c(1:5))
df2 = data.frame(x=c(1:5), y=c(6:10))
df3 = data.frame(x=c(1:8), y=c(9:16), z=c(17:24))

lista_df = list(df1, df2, df3)
```

### Salva a lista no arquivo lista_df.rds

```
saveRDS(lista_df, "lista_df.rds")
```

### Carrega a lista para o arquivo lista_df_new

```
lista_df_new = readRDS("lista_df.rds")
```

### Converte a lista para data.frames

```
for (i in 1:length(lista_df_new)){
  assign(paste("df",i, sep=""), value = data.frame(lista_df_new[[i]]) ) 
}
```